# How do I compile libcache?

Tags: linux, sublime-text-2

I have been trying to use the much talked about `SublimeClang` plugin for Sublime Text 2, which gives me an error that `libcache.so` could not be loaded, and in Linux, I am supposed to compile it manually.

I have seen some posts where people mention that they had compiled it and put it into `/usr/local/lib`, but oddly enough, I cannot seem to find any text on how to compile libcache!

Compiling CLang was easy enough, but I cannot really figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do:

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/SublimeClang/src/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: Thank you! I did that, and it worked, but not for long. As soon as I do `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, the whole build directory disappears. How do I stop it? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I realized this happening sometimes too. It seems Package Control cleans the directory somehow. I now installed SublimeClang using git clone of SublimeClang inside the Packages directory. I don't have the problem anymore.